# Rails convert links to bootstrap buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have built some code that sorts an index page, using links in my view. This works fine with links, and the working code is this:

```
<p>
  <%= link_to "Sentence", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '1', :class => "btn" %>
  <%= link_to "Question", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '2', :class => "btn" %>
  <%= link_to "Mnemonic", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '3', :class => "btn"  %>
  <%= link_to "Article", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '4', :class => "btn"  %>
  <%= link_to "Recommendation", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '5', :class => "btn"  %>
</p>
```

I would like to use a button group, and have built this example using Twitter Bootstrap in plain HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">Sentence</button>
  <button class="btn">Question</button>
  <button class="btn">Mnemonic</button>
  <button class="btn">Article</button>
  <button class="btn">Recommendation</button>
</div>
```

I cannot get the links converted to the button row. I have tried various styling options as well as attempting to use **button_to**. Ideally I would like to further style the buttons so that the currently selected one is a different color than the others.

**EDIT**

Output of HTML as suggested:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="/dialog_catagories?class=btn&amp;type=1">Sentence</a>
  <a href="/dialog_catagories?class=btn&amp;type=2">Question</a>
  <a href="/dialog_catagories?class=btn&amp;type=3">Mnemonic</a>
  <a href="/dialog_catagories?class=btn&amp;type=4">Article</a>
  <a href="/dialog_catagories?class=btn&amp;type=5">Recommendation</a>
</div>
```

The btn-group is preventing the buttons from rendering on the page for some reason, even though it is in the html.

**EDIT 2**

HTML code as per Varun's answer:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a href="/dialog_catagories?html%5Bclass%5D=btn&amp;type=1">Sentence</a>
  <a href="/dialog_catagories?html%5Bclass%5D=btn&amp;type=2">Question</a>
  <a href="/dialog_catagories?html%5Bclass%5D=btn&amp;type=3">Mnemonic</a>
  <a href="/dialog_catagories?html%5Bclass%5D=btn&amp;type=4">Article</a>
  <a href="/dialog_catagories?html%5Bclass%5D=btn&amp;type=5">Recommendation</a>
</div>
```

**SOLUTION**

@Varun's suggested answer worked in the end:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <%= link_to "Sentence", "?type=1", :class => "btn" %>
  <%= link_to "Question", "?type=2", :class => "btn" %>
</div>
```

I am a bit unclear how the functionality is still working, as the following is not being explicitly passed:

```
:controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action]
```

But it is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: Actually they are still being rendered as links in the html, which is probably why they don't appear in the btn-group. They render as links if the btn-group class is left out.

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me what version of bootstrap you have linked? And also what version of rails since your :class parameter wasn't picked up....

Comment: Each link should have the class `btn` on it and they should be in a div with the class `btn-group` that's it.

Comment: Rails 3.2.6 and Bootstrap 2. In the outputted html you can see the class=btn in the href.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <%= link_to "Sentence", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '1', :html => { :class => "btn" } %>
  <%= link_to "Question", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '2', :html => { :class => "btn" } %>
  <%= link_to "Mnemonic", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '3', :html => { :class => "btn" } %>
  <%= link_to "Article", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '4', :html => { :class => "btn" }  %>
  <%= link_to "Recommendation", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '5', :html => { :class => "btn" } %>
</div>
```

**Edit**

Try this:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <%= link_to "Sentence", "?type=1", :class => "btn" %>
  <%= link_to "Question", "?type=2", :class => "btn" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Varun. I am afraid it still is not rendering them. See edit 2 above.

Comment: Varun that was it. Fantastic! Thanks for your efforts. Thank you also Tigraine.

Answer (score 4):

I'm still on Rails 2 and the html=> { :class => :btn } wasn't working for me.

I did this and it renders/works nicely

```
        <div class="btn-group">
          <%= link_to "Pool my Order", 
             {:controller => :purchasing, :action => :search_for_salesdoc,
              :sold_to_number => sold_to, doc_number => @cart.doc_number, 
              :search_option => :pool},
             :class => "btn btn-success align-center" %>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Whats wrong with your first code but converting the p to a ? Bootstrap links can be styled like buttons with class 'btn'

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <%= link_to "Sentence", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '1', :class => "btn" %>
  <%= link_to "Question", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '2', :class => "btn" %>
  <%= link_to "Mnemonic", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '3', :class => "btn"  %>
  <%= link_to "Article", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '4', :class => "btn"  %>
  <%= link_to "Recommendation", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '5', :class => "btn"  %>
</div>
```

This should world.. Doing the select detection is also not that hard, just add a check into the link_to:

```
  <%= link_to "Recommendation", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :type => '5', :class => selected? ? "btn btn-primary" : "btn"  %>
```

you still have to to somehow implement the selected? helper but I guess you can figure this out.

*Update*:
It seems your link_to helper is the problem because you use the controller, action in there.
I think the right way for your link_to methods is:

```
link_to "Sentence", :controller => :foo, :action => :bar, :html => { :class => :btn }
```

Comment: Thanks. I have the implementation of the selected working OK, it's really the appearance I am after. I tried the suggested code but strangely doesn't display anything on the page. I've posted the rendered HTML in the original question. The problem seems to be the class="btn-group" code.

Comment: You can have it go to a specific route as follows: <%= link_to 'My Route', myroute_path, :class => "btn btn-warning" %> or whatever button style you choose to use